# Force double to display 2 decimal points

Tags: java, linked-list, double, tostring

Bit of a silly one, but just to clarify I know I can format the output to a string and then format the string in a variety of ways to achieve this but I need the return value to stay as a double as it has multiple uses.

So basically I have a `LinkedList` that i am reading values in from that was formatted as a double when imported. I am then using the sum of these values to essentially calculate a total which I am using in a `toString` function and a couple of other places.

My issue is if there are trailing zeros they are trimed so the values is as small as possible. e.g: 3.50 -> 3.5, 0.00 -> 0.0 and so on.

```
public double totalCost(){
        double total = 0.00;
        for(Ingredient cost : ingredients){
            total += cost.ingredientCost();
        }
        return total;
```

The code above is the sum code.

```
public String toString(){
        return crust() + " pizza with " + toppings() + " and " + sauce() + ": $" + totalCost();
    }
```

And this is my `toString` function.

Any guidance would be awesome.

Comment: So if you know how to format a double to a String, what are you actually asking?  A double is just a number, so there's no such thing as "a double storing 3.5" and "a double storing 3.500" being somehow different.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
public String toString(){
    return crust() + " pizza with " + toppings() + " and " + sauce() + ": $" + String.format( "%.2f", totalCost());
}
```